# How to extract array values from mysql json field and return null or default if path does not exist?

Tags: mysql, mysql-json, json-extract

I have this json in a mysql column.

```
{"items": [
    {
         "name": "a1",
         "details": {"value": 1}
    },
    {
         "name": "a2",
         "details": {"value": 2}
    },
    {
         "name": "a3"
    },
    {
         "name": "a4",
         "details": {"value": 4}
    },
 ]
}
```

As you can see `details` is an optional field for each item. when i try to extract value from this column using `JSON_EXTRACT(column, '$.items[*].details.value')`, i get
`[1,2,4]` but i would like to get `[1,2,null,4]` instead. If the path does not exist, i would like to get null or any default value. Is it possible using mysql JSON_EXTRACT?